# Re-used Zero-to-One FK relationships in EF Code First with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, data-annotations

I've got some code that isn't producing the FK relationships I want in the database.

I have two objects, let's call them Deals and Salespeople. A Deal can have zero, one, or both of two separate Salespeople recorded: one is the Negotiator who created the Deal, one is the Closer who closed the Deal. So that's two separate 0:1 relationships to the same table.

Additionally we'll say the Deal has a Creator who's a user in the system, that's whatever system user happened to do data entry on the information. I'm including that entry to show how I've done all the rest of my foreign key relationships in my solution, which is working great (giving me control over the key naming and everything).

Here's my (stripped-down) code:

```
[Table("Salespersons")]
public class Salesperson
{
    // constructor and whatnot

    [Key, Column("SalespersonId")]
    public int SalesId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Negotiator")]
    public virtual ICollection<Deal> NegotiatedDeals { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Closer")]
    public virtual ICollection<Deal> ClosedDeals { get; set; }
}

[Table("Deals")]
public class Deal
{
    // constructor, misc properties etc

    [Key]
    public int DealId { get; set; }

    // This lets me govern the name of the DB field for the FK & works correctly
    [ForeignKey("Creator"), MaxLength(128)]
    public string CreatorUser { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUser Creator { get; set; }

    // This doesn't work: no FK relationships generated
    [ForeignKey("Closer")]
    public int? CloserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Salesperson Closer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Negotiator")]
    public int? NegotiatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Salesperson Negotiator { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to figure out how to make EF create the Negotiator (FK to Salesperson) and Closer (FK to Salesperson) foreign key relationships using Data Annotations only, but if there are other code-managed solutions which can make this happen I'm open to it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me..EF generated NegotiatorId and CloserId in the Deals table both FKs to Salespersons (or salespeople) table.

Comment: ...bizarre. I agree it definitely **should** work, everything seems to be following the instructions laid out in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx) -- it just... isn't! Thanks for checking it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Attribute way for deals, I would do through `EntityTypeConfiguration`

```
public class DealMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Deal>
{
   public DealMapping()
   {
      ToTable("Deals");
      HasKey(c=>c.DealId);
      HasOptional(d => d.Closer).WithMany(s=>s.ClosedDeals).HasForeignKey(p=>p.CloserId);
      HasOptional(d => d.Negotiator).WithMany(s=>s.NegotiatedDeals).HasForeignKey(p=>p.NegotiatorId);
   }
}
```

and in your `DbContext`,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  /*Other mappings*/
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add((new DealMapping());
}
```

Comment: This is great--thank you! Though all other DB configuration in the system is managed through data annotations, so I would definitely like to find a DA-based solution if I can.